# Rails - How to send an image from a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, open-uri

in my rails app, I need to pass back a image.

I have a 1x1.gif tracking pixel in my route as follows:

```
 match "/_ctrack.gif" => "email_tracking_pixels#my_method"
```

In the controller:

```
def my_method
    send_data open('https://www.xxxxxx.com/images/1x1_transparent.gif') {|f| f.read }, :filename => '1x1_transparent.gif', :type => 'image/gif'
end
```

The problem is that for some reason sometimes this times outs. with the following error:

```
2011-03-07T20:08:36-08:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET www.xxxxxxx.com/images/1x1_transparent.gif dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-03-07T20:08:36-08:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-03-07T20:08:36-08:00 app[web.1]: OpenURI::HTTPError (503 Service Unavailable):
2011-03-07T20:08:36-08:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/email_tracking_pixels_controller.rb:19:in `my_method'
2011-03-07T20:08:36-08:00 app[web.1]:   lib/rack/www.rb:7:in `call'
```

Any ideas on how I can pass this image that's stored locally, versus having to use open and make a web call back to my own server?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is there a reason that you cannot save the file to `public/_ctrack.gif`, remove the route, and let the underlying web server serve the image?

If you need to process the image from disk, just use [`open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001399) on the local filename:

```
send_data open("#{Rails.root}/path/to/file.gif", "rb") { |f| f.read } .......
```

The `rb` sets the file to `open` and `binary` modes.

Comment: I didn't know open could do that.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but this may work too, doesn't require a block, and closes the file when done: `send_data File.read("/path/to/file", :mode => "rb"), :filename => '1x1_transparent.gif', :type => 'image/gif'`

Answer (score 50):

Wouldn't be better to use send_file instead?

```
send_file Rails.root.join("public", "file.gif"), type: "image/gif", disposition: "inline"
```

Comment: `send_file` would be a much better alternative and can take advantage of X-SendFile or X-Accel-Redirect headers in your web server to avoid tying up a ruby process.

Comment: This provides much better behavior on the client side.